# How to find the radius of a circle given three points in 3d space C#

Tags: c#, math, 3d, geometry

I have locations of three points along the circle. `pt1(x1, y1,z1)`, `pt2(x2, y2, z2)`, `pt3(x3, y3,z3)`. and **want to find the radius of the circle. Already I have a function to compute radius in 2d space, which I am copying it here**

```
public static double ComputeRadius(Location a, Location b, Location c)
        {
            double x1 = a.x;
            double y1 = a.y;
            double x2 = b.x;
            double y2 = b.y;
            double x3 = c.x;
            double y3 = c.y;
            double mr = (double)((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
            double mt = (double)((y3 - y2) / (x3 - x2));

            double xc = (double)((mr * mt * (y3 - y1) + mr * (x2 + x3) - mt * (x1 + x2)) / (2 * (mr - mt)));

            double yc = (double)((-1 / mr) * (xc - (x1 + x2) / 2) + (y1 + y2) / 2);
            double d = (xc - x1) * (xc - x1) + (yc - y1) * (yc - y1);

            return Math.Sqrt(d);
        }
```

Comment: This is related to math. Does not deal much with programming. Programming side: just some operation of numbers. Math side: ask it on mathematics

Comment: can't we compute radius unless we know 4 points?

Comment: @MohamedSirajudeen: sorry - I read 'sphere' instead of 'circle'. Three points a totally ok.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure thus commenting instead of answering, but taking the length of the sides of the triangle that those 3d points form (which would be a matter of doing `sqrt(pow(x1-x2,2) + pow(y1-y2,2) + pow(z1-z2,2))`, etc.), if we name those lengths `la`,`lb`,and `lc`, the formula for finding the radius would be: `2*la*lb*lc / sqrt((la+lb+lc)*(lb+lc-la)*(la+lc-lb)*(la+lb-lc))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build Circle from 3 Points in 3D space implementation in C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977354/build-circle-from-3-points-in-3d-space-implementation-in-c-or-c)

Comment: See here forexample http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16209/how-to-determine-the-center-and-radius-of-a-circle-given-some-points-in-3d

Answer (score 2):

If you know the order of points `pt1,pt2,pt3` along the circle then you can use graphical method:

1. **cast normal axises from middle of each line segment in the plane of circle**

   your circle plane is defined by your 3 points. so the normal vector is

   ```
   n = (pt2-pt1) x (pt3-pt2)
   ```

   where the `x` is cross product so you have 2 lines `(pt1,pt2)` and `(pt2,pt3)` in black. The mid points are easy

   ```
   p0=0.5*(pt1+pt2)
   p1=0.5*(pt2+pt3)
   ```

   the axis directions can be obtained also by cross product

   ```
   dp0=(pt2-pt1) x n
   dp1=(pt3-pt2) x n
   ```

   so you got 2 axises:

   ```
   pnt0(t)=p0+dp0*t
   pnt1(u)=p1+dp1*u
   ```

   Where `t,u` are scalar parameters `t,u=(-inf,+inf)` it is just position in axis from the starting mid point ...
2. **the intersection is center of circle**

   So find the [intersection of 2 axises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) and call it `pt0`
3. **compute distance between center and any of your points**

   ```
   r=|pt1-pt0|
   ```

[image: curve radius]

Sorry the image is for any curve (too lazy to repaint for circle as it is almost the same). If you do not know the order of points then the 2 points that are most distant to each other are the outer points ... In case they are equidistant the order does not matter any is OK

Comment: thanks @Spektre for your time. I will apply your solution and let you know.

Comment: @MohamedSirajudeen OK just spotted I got just single line parameter there are 2 ... one for each axis line ... have edited it (`t,u` instead just `t`)

Comment: You don't really need to know the order of the points, right? Only an assurance that they really are three _different_ points.

Comment: @Ángela Well after some taught  about this I think you're right the order is needed for arbitrary curvature on circle it is not important... the result will be the same (so +1)